# split with no argument in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl, and I wonder what this line of code mean?

```
($q,$dummy, $d,$v) = split;
```

I search through google, but i found no explanation of using split without argument, does this kind of use related to the "while" block?

And the full code fragment is:

```
open(T,"$opt_judgments") ||  die "can't open judgment file: $opt_judgments\n";
while (<T>) {
  if ($opt_trec) {
    ($q,$dummy, $d,$v) = split;
  } else {
    ($q,$d,$v) = split;
  }
  $dict{$q ."=".$d} =$v;
  if ($v != 0) {
    $totalRels{$q} ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: I just try that, cool perl development environment is!

Comment: "I search through google" - That's your mistake. You're better off searching for Perl information at http://perldoc.perl.org/ or http://metacpan.org/.

Comment: Searching using Google is quite good if you use a query like `site:perldoc.perl.org split`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It splits the current line (`$_`) on whitespace. Quoting the manual:

> If EXPR is omitted, splits the $_ string.  If PATTERN is also omitted, splits on whitespace (after skipping any leading whitespace).

Answer (score 5):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

The general syntax of split is:

```
split /PATTERN/,EXPR
```

If `EXPR` is omitted, it splits the `$_` string.

If `PATTERN` is also omitted, splits on whitespace (after skipping any leading whitespace). Anything matching `PATTERN` is taken to be a delimiter separating the fields. (Note that the delimiter may be longer than one character.)

Since in your case both `PATTERN` and `EXPR` are omitted. A split of `$_` on whitespace occurs and the first four pieces of the split are assigned to `$q`, `$dummy`, `$d` and `$v` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive explanation! Seems that I'm so new to this.

Comment: ...so `split()` is the same as `split(' ', $_)`