# Function name inside parentheses in Perl one liner

Tags: perl

I'm working on a Perl one liner [tutorial](http://www.ccg.unam.mx/~vinuesa/tlem/pdfs/TPR_one-liners.pdf) and there are one liners like this:

```
ls -lAF | perl -e 'while (<>) {next if /^[dt]/; print +(split)[8] . " size: " . +(split)[4] . "\n"}'
```

You see the function name **split** has been inside parentheses. Documentation about this use of functions is hard to find on Google so I couldn't find any information on it. Could somebody explain it? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634937/split-with-no-argument-in-perl)?

Comment: The tutorial you're using says this: *"Most talented unix Perl programmers I have met have a dirty little secret. They cannot resist the allure of
the gnarly Perl one-liner for accomplishing short tasks that do not need a complete script."* I have found quite the opposite: anyone who knows Perl at all well will hate the *one-liner* with a passion. It is a device from bash that allows you to write single-line Perl programs, and the only people who like them are newcomers to the language and people who like to show off.

Comment: In my opinion, no one other than Perl experts should even consider attempting a one-liner, and if that restriction were in place no one ever would. I think you're seeing it as a soft introduction to Perl, when in fact it is by far the very hardest. The facility remains only as a backward-compatibility thing, and the modern facilities like `strict` and lexical variables are unavailable unless you use `perl -Mstrict` which has lost 10% of the line already, plus another 3 characters for every `my `. There's no reason not to source a proper Perl program from a `.pl` file.

Comment: @raina77ow no I haven't seen that question. As I mentioned, it was so hard to search that particular topic because the phrase 'parentheses' interfered so much with the 'calling a function with arguments inside parentheses' topics, so I gave up searching. That post was useful, thank you for that.

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for the comments, they've been enlightening for me. You're correct I'm a newcomer to the Perl. After I noticed Perl's similarities  to Javascript, PHP and Ruby and because Perl was designed years before them,I found it highly interesting and decided to learn intricacies of it. That's why I got stuck in the one liners as they seemed so interesting. But I practice them as way to warm up for the real Perl applications, to be able to write my own Perl scripts in the near future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably doesn't help that the use of `split` is defaulting everything - it's splitting `$_` by spaces and returning a list of values.

The `(...)[8]` is called a list slice, and it filters out all but the 9th value returned by `split`. The preceding plus is there to prevent Perl from misparsing the brackets as being part of a function call. Which also means you don't need it on the second instance.

So `print +(split)[8];` is basically a very succinct way of writing

```
my @results=split(/ /,$_);
print $results[8];
```

The example you've included is performing the `split` twice so it might be more efficient to do the more verbose version as you can get `$results[4]` from the above without any extra effort.

Or because you can put a list of indexes inside the `[]`, you could do the split once and use printf to format the output like this

```
printf "%s size: %s\n", (split)[8,4];
```

Comment: You might want to go into detail how `split` returns a list, and the `(...)[4]` essentially uses the return value in list context, and accesses the 5th element of that list, discarding the whole list afterwards.

Comment: @simbabque aside from not mentioning what `split` returns, isn't that what I said?

Comment: You're describing `+(...)` as a unit, followed by `[8]`. But `(` `)[` `]` is actually a single operator (list slicing). You can't have a bare `[8]`.

Comment: The plus sign is really disambiguous. Where is it documented as a 'no-op' operator? Google search and perldoc didn't return any useful info. I use perlbrew on a Mac;maybe perldoc was not installed in full, perldoc no-op returns No documentation found for "no-op".

Comment: @Romario, Operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). *Unary "`+`" has no effect whatsoever, even on strings. It is useful syntactically for separating a function name from a parenthesized expression that would otherwise be interpreted as the complete list of function arguments.*

Comment: *"is basically a very succinct way of writing

`my @results=split(/ /,$_)` ..."* No, it's not. It's equivalent to `my @results=split(' ', $_)` and the distinction is very important. This is generally a poor-quality answer, as your *"It probably doesn't help that the use of split is defaulting everything"* is also baseless.

Comment: @Borodin there are no parameters being passed to `split` so how is it not using default values for all of them?

Comment: @Chris: It is using default parameters, but that makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Borodin the OP was confused by what the code meant so I was covering all bases

Comment: @Romario: *"Disambiguous"* isn't an English word. Can you explain what you meant here?

Comment: @Borodin I was aware of the wrong use of the word 'disambiguous'  I meant 'unclear' od course. The plus sign there is unclear or tricky for the uninitiated.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should be avoiding this author's advice, both for the reasons laid out in my comments on your question, and because they don't appear to know their topic at all well.

The original "one-liner" was this

```
ls -lAF | perl -e 'while (<>) {next if /^[dt]/; print +(split)[8] . " size: " . +(split)[4] . "\n"}'
```

This could be written much more succinctly by using the `-n` and `-a` options, giving this

```
ls -lAF | perl -wane 'print $F[8] size: $F[4]\n" unless /^[dt]/'
```

Even without the "luxury" of these options you could write

```
ls -lAF | perl -e '/^[dt]/ or printf "%s size: %s\n", (split)[8,4]  while <>'
```

I recommend that you go and read the [*Camel Book*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) several times over the next few years. That is the best way to learn the language that I have found.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It's as much helpful as the one I ticked as the answer. The one liner which uses the special variable F is particularly enlightening and the next one which puts the regexp to the front and making use of the 'or' construct is fine too; it shows the flexibility of the Perl.

Comment: And as for the Camel Book, actually I've got that book and read several pages of it. But for this particular problem, it was of no use because I had to search against a very generic term 'parenthesis' resulting in hundreds of matches, all seeming similar to each other.

Comment: @Romario FWIW: I find `perldoc` to be a great *reference tool* for looking things up in the moment.  Just get accustomed to what's in each sub-page.  I find the Camel Book on the other hand to be more useful in my down-time, to teach/remind one of how to best use Perl's strengths.

Answer (score 1):

Most installations of Perl include a full set of documentation, accessible using the `perldoc` command.

You need to read the [*Slices* section of `perldoc perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) which makes very clear this use of slicing.